# Why red laser doesn't appear on the black color

Tags: 3d, scanning, imaging

I am working on a 3D scanner project, i used a line laser and some other stuff, the laser is to help getting the 3rd dimension, any way i'm finishing up this project.

But i have a problem with the objects that has a black color, the problem is:

the laser line doesn't appear on the black regions of any object, it may absorb the laser or i'm not sure what the problem is, any one could help i would be very thankful

here is some photos to make it easy to understand what am saying.

An [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EFIS.jpg) for an object with line laser on

and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vydDw.jpg) is just the laser line

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is *physics*. [Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black#Optics) objects absorb [large percentage of] visible light. White objects are the exact opposite.

In order for the object to be seen (by you, or the camera), it needs to reflect light. Therefore, there will always be a significant difference between the brightness of the laser line as seen by the camera on black vs. white background. You should expect this to happen, and write your code accordingly.

---

*NB: The following is opinion/experience based.*

Based on the image you provided, it seems that the contrast ratio between ambient light and the laser line is quite low.

In a 3D scanner, you're interested in the laser line -- anything else is noise, and therefore you should do your best to eliminate it. I'd probably aim for max. ambient intensity being at most 10%.

Two options come to mind:

1. Shielding -- put the system in a box, so that the only light there is that produced by the laser. This may be somewhat impractical, but ultimately cheaper.
2. Lower exposure time. The better approach, but it also means the laser appears dimmer as well (so, no gain alone).

As mentioned above, laser line is the target. Therefore, maximum laser line intensity should be close to the maximum intensity that can be represented in the image. Since you want to scan black objects, you probably want to allow for some clipping (i.e. some camera pixels getting saturated) in the white areas.

Two options again:

1. Longer exposure time. Unfortunately this leads to the first problem with ambient light, and limits the speed of scanning.
2. More powerful laser. This would be the ideal solution, however (just a rough guess) it would be something like 10-50 mW (class 3B, so there are safety implications and depending on where you use it probably various regulations to observe).